# возникает исключение при парсинге

Tags: python, requests, bs4, lxml

Захотел спарсить  [сайт](http://igri-2012.ru/) вроде всё вышло но захотел усложнить парсер , задача была переходить по каждому фрагменту с игрой и забирать ссылку на торрент, вроде requests переходит по ссылке даже отдаёт данные но потом выдаёт исключение вот код :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

headers = {
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36',
'Referer': 'http://igri-2012.ru/'
}
ua = UserAgent()
url = 'http://igri-2012.ru/'
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(req, 'lxml')

content = soup.find('div', id="content")
block_game = content.find_all('div', class_="gk-box column gk-box-left")
for item in block_game:
    link = item.find('div', class_="moduletable nsp clear").find('h4').find('a').get('href')
    name = item.find('img', class_="nsp_image tleft fnone").get('title')
    img = item.find('img', class_="nsp_image tleft fnone").get('src')

    download_storage = requests.get(link, ua.random).text
    downlod_soup = BeautifulSoup(req, 'lxml')

    print(download_storage)
```

а вот исключение :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Projects\ParserBundestag\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "E:\Projects\ParserBundestag\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 445, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "E:\Projects\ParserBundestag\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 440, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Python 3.9.0\lib\http\client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Python 3.9.0\lib\http\client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Python 3.9.0\lib\http\client.py", line 276, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Projects\ParserBundestag\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "E:\Projects\ParserBundestag\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "E:\Projects\ParserBundestag\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 531, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "E:\Projects\ParserBundestag\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 734, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "E:\Projects\ParserBundestag\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "E:\Projects\ParserBundestag\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 445, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "E:\Projects\ParserBundestag\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 440, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Python 3.9.0\lib\http\client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Python 3.9.0\lib\http\client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Python 3.9.0\lib\http\client.py", line 276, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Projects\ParserBundestag\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    download_storage = requests.get(link, ua.random).text
  File "E:\Projects\ParserBundestag\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Projects\ParserBundestag\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Projects\ParserBundestag\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "E:\Projects\ParserBundestag\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Projects\ParserBundestag\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

[image: Воот как то так]

Comment: Пробовал fake_useragent вместо headers в requests подставить , нечего не меняется (

Comment: Remote end closed connection without response